# Datetime format error

Tags: sql-server

I am getting an invalid date when trying to convert `DATETIME` to `VARCHAR`.

This is the query I use:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 131)
```

This is the output it returns:

```
15/05/1434 11:53:26:073AM
```

Comment: what are you expecting? the result is the same as here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11566

Comment: Output format should be dd/mm/yy hh:mi:ss

Comment: That seems to be what is expected with a Hijri date. Try it out here. [Hijri Converter](http://www.islamicity.com/PrayerTimes/hijriconverter1aPartner.htm)

Comment: It's usually best to keep datetime values as datetimes within the database, and only format it as a string at the last possible moment (e.g. in your UI's view code, or using your report generator's formatting facilities, or however you're actually processing your results)

Answer (score 2):

There is no exact conversion that will get you exactly dd/mm/yy hh:mi:ss unless you want Hijiri.

To get close you will be forced to use:

```
SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(),105) --dd-mm-yy
+ ' ' + CONVERT( VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(),108 ) -- hh:mi:ss
```

Example: [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11582)

For more information please view the MSDN library for [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Note: If the forward slashes are required (vs. Dashes) you will need to use [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This is display Hijiri date time format.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

you can check your current date with Hijiri date time format by below URL.

http://www.islamicfinder.org/dateConversion.php?mode=ger-hij&day=26&month=3&year=2013&date_result=1

I have not such detail about Hijiri date time format. but result gives correct when you use 130 and 131 convert format.

Comment: i need Output format like dd/mm/yy hh:mi:ss.. How can i get it in normal calender

Comment: tried with this SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 103) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 108) AS CurrentDate